# Create directory tree in Perl that would comply with Fancytree expected JSON format

Tags: perl, tree-traversal, fancytree

How to create directory tree in *Perl* to comply with *Fancytree* expected JSON [format](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#define-the-tree-data)?

This is the *Perl* part I came up with, that traverses through given path:

```
sub get_tree
{
    my ($gpath) = @_;
    my %r;

    use File::Find;
    my $c = sub {
        my $dir  = $File::Find::dir;
        my $r    = \%r;

        my $tdir = $dir;
        $tdir    =~ s|^\Q$gpath\E/?||;

        $r = $r->{$_} ||= {} for split m|/|, $tdir;
    };
    find($c, $gpath);
    return \%r;
}
```

It returns the following result after JSON encode:

```
 {
  "dir3":{

  },
  "dir1":{
    "sub-dir2":{

    },
    "sub-dir1":{

    }
  },
  "dir2":{
    "sub-dir1":{
      "sub-sub-dir1":{
        "sub-sub-sub-dir1":{

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The expected result for *Fancytree* to comply with its JSON [format](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#define-the-tree-data) is:

```
[
    {"parent": "dir3"},
    {"parent": "dir2", "child": [
       {"parent": "sub-dir1", "child": [
          {"parent": "sub-sub-dir1", "child": [
             {"parent": "sub-sub-sub-dir1"}
          ]}
       ]}
    ]},
    {"parent": "dir1", "child": [
       {"parent": "sub-dir1"},
       {"parent": "sub-dir1"}
    ]}
]
```

The point is to do it in a single run, without post processing, which would be ideal.

Any help of how to achieve that?

Comment: Once you've built this, you should put it on CPAN.

Comment: @simbabque Sounds good. :)

Comment: Could you include a shell script to create the exact directory structure you are using please?

Comment: It's Perl. Just paste it to the `.cgi` file with `#!/usr/bin/perl`, add the sub there and then run it. Example: `get_tree('/root')`. That's all.

Comment: You misunderstand. I want code to create a directory structure that matches your exact one in your example so I can copy/paste your code and your expected output to test against. I don't want to fiddle with getting the correct folders manually. Something like `mkdir dir1; mkdir dir1/sub-dir1` and so on.

Comment: Okay, I see, here is the Perl file to use: https://gist.github.com/qooob/0cf71b699bb9c2446ca14a0b2c01b04d and I will post the command, hold on a second.

Comment: Do you really want only the directories in the structure, or should there be files in there as well? If so, then what should they look like, as a `parent` field is irrelevant?

Comment: @Borodin I only expect directories to be there, no files. It's the tree-view that I'm making for Authentic Theme for Webmin/Usermin.

Comment: @simbabque Run it on the console to create the same directory structure. `mkdir paths && cd "$_" && mkdir dir3 && mkdir dir2 && mkdir dir1 && cd "$_" mkdir sub-dir1; mkdir sub-dir2; cd ../dir2; mkdir sub-dir1 && cd "$_" && mkdir sub-sub-dir1 && cd "$_" && mkdir sub-sub-sub-dir1`. Then you can use it as `get_tree('/tmp/paths')`.

Comment: Putting `use` into a sub is confusing. It's called when the sub is compiled, not when it's run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub get_tree {
    my ($gpath) = @_;
    my %r;
    my @root;

    use File::Find;
    my $cb = sub {

        my $tdir = $File::Find::dir;
        $tdir    =~ s|^\Q$gpath\E/?||;
        return if $r{$tdir} or !$tdir;

        my ($pdir, $cdir) = $tdir =~ m|^ (.+) / ([^/]+) \z|x;
        my $c = $r{$tdir} = { parent => $cdir // $tdir };

        if (defined $pdir) { push @{ $r{$pdir}{child} }, $c }
        else { push @root, $c }

    };
    find($cb, $gpath);
    return \@root;
}
```

It uses hash for fast lookup of nodes, and complete directory structure is built atop of `@root`.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you, pal!

Comment: Is there a way to optimize potentially slow regex: `s|^\Q$gpath\E/?||;`

Comment: Besides, as I was trying to find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338323/perl-filefind-name-and-dir-subs-not-returning-expected-results-on-empty-ta), `$File::Find::dir` ignores empty directories. There are commenters stating that `$File::Find::dir` will still use `$File::Find::name` and that makes me very iffy, because it doesn't sound efficient. Do you know the way to force `::dir` to collect empty directories as well?

Comment: For Fancytree to work labels should be `title` and `children`, by the way but this is trivial.

Comment: The code does not output empty directories. @IliaRostovtsev is it what you want?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Re: regex, don't know how to optimize regex, but `-d or return;` before it would skip rest of the function when file is handed over, so potentially skipping some unneeded work.

Comment: No, as I'm creating directory tree-view, all directories should be in the list.

@Сухой27 Last question, how hard it is to sort output lexicographically? It's the directory tree so it must be sorted. Using simply sort will not work obviously.

Comment: Didn't try it, but perhaps `find({wanted=>$c, preprocess=> sub { sort @_ } }, $gpath)`

Comment: @Сухой27 Simply genius. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion instead of File::Find, using [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny) to handle paths:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Tiny;
sub get_tree {
    my ($struct, $root, @path) = @_;
    for my $child (path($root, @path)->children) {
        if (-d $child) {
            my $base = $child->basename;
            push @$struct, { parent => $base };
            my $recurse = get_tree($struct->[-1]{child} = [],
                                   $root, @path, $base);
            delete $struct->[-1]{child} unless @$recurse;
        }
    }
    return $struct
}

use Test::More tests => 1;
use Test::Deep;

my $expected = bag({parent => 'dir1',
                    child => bag(
                        {parent => 'sub-dir1'},
                        {parent => 'sub-dir2'})},
                   {parent => 'dir2',
                    child => bag(
                       {parent => 'sub-dir1',
                        child  => bag({
                           parent => 'sub-sub-dir1',
                           child  => bag({
                               parent => 'sub-sub-sub-dir1'
                           })})})},
                   {parent => 'dir3'});

my $tree = get_tree([], 'paths');
cmp_deeply $tree, $expected, 'same';
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is correct (makes Fancytree on client-side just load), however it's much slower than my initial example. For instance, my `get_tree()` returns the all paths starting from `/` in about 1 second. Your example takes forever for `/`, but `/etc` works alright. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: I don't think we should use `Path::Tiny`,at first, it's not the part of the core modules and second it seems to be slower. Would you like to optimize your code?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev: Feel free to tweak the code as you like.

Comment: sure, okay. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following would produce the structure you wanted.

**test.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

sub get_json
{
    return JSON->new->latin1->pretty->encode(@_);
}

sub get_tree
{
    my ($gpath) = @_;
    my (%r,@rr);

    use File::Find;
    my $c = sub {
        my $dir  = $File::Find::name;
        my $r    = \%r;
        my $rr   = \@rr;

        my $tdir = $dir;
        $tdir    =~ s|^\Q$gpath\E/?||;

        my $previtem;
        for my $item(split m|/|, $tdir) {
            if ($previtem) {
                $rr=$r->{$previtem}[1]{child}//=[];
                $r= $r->{$previtem}[0]{child}//={};
            }
            $r->{$item} //= [ { }, $rr->[@$rr]= { parent=>$item } ];    
            $previtem = $item;
        }
   };
    find($c, $gpath);
    return \%r,\@rr;
}

my ($r,$rr) = get_tree($ARGV[0]);
print get_json($rr);
```

**output**

```
[
   {
      "parent" : "test.pl"
   },
   {
      "parent" : "dir1",
      "child" : [
         {
            "parent" : "sub-dir1"
         },
         {
            "parent" : "sub-dir2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "parent" : "dir2",
      "child" : [
         {
            "parent" : "sub-dir1",
            "child" : [
               {
                  "parent" : "sub-sub-dir1"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "parent" : "dir3"
   }
]
```

---

I've run it: `perl test.pl .`. So you see 'test.pl' in the output

In case you want to traverse only directories, change the find call to:

```
find({wanted=>$c, preprocess=> sub { grep { -d  $_ } @_; } }, $gpath);
```

Comment: Putting `use` into a sub is confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The output that is produced unfortunately incorrect. More details here: https://gist.github.com/qooob/0cf71b699bb9c2446ca14a0b2c01b04d

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev, the gist shows the output of the first value returned by `get_tree` from my answer. The structure you need is actually returned in the second value. Check how the output is printed at the bottom ot the code.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats Yes it does. It's not entirely wrong, it's just different. This is why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing, here is the final code, that will produce valid *JSON* object expected by [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) out of the box. Thanks to everyone, who was generous to spend time and provide help.

**Perl:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

=head2 get_tree(path, [depth])    

Build sorted directory tree in format expected by Fancytree

=item path - The path from which to start searching.
=item depth - The optional parameter to limit the depth.

=cut

use File::Find;
use JSON;

sub get_tree {
  my ( $p, $d ) = @_;
  my $df = int($d);
  my %r;
  my @r;

  my $wanted = sub {
    my $td = $File::Find::name;
    if ( -d $td ) {
        $td =~ s|^\Q$p\E/?||;
        if ( $r{$td} || !$td ) {
            return;
        }
        my ( $pd, $cd ) = $td =~ m|^ (.+) / ([^/]+) \z|x;
        my $pp = $p ne '/' ? $p : undef;
        my $c = $r{$td} = {
            key   => "$pp/$td",
            title => ( defined($cd) ? $cd : $td )
        };
        defined $pd ? ( push @{ $r{$pd}{children} }, $c ) : ( push @r, $c );
    }
  };
  my $preprocess = sub {
    my $dd = ( $df > 0 ? ( $df + 1 ) : 0 );
    if ($dd) {
        my $d = $File::Find::dir =~ tr[/][];
        if ( $d < $dd ) {
            return sort @_;
        }
        return;
    }
    sort @_;
  };
  find(
    {
        wanted     => $wanted,
        preprocess => $preprocess
    },
    $p
);
return \@r;
}


# Retrieve JSON tree of `/home` with depth of `5`
JSON->new->encode(get_tree('/home', 5));
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.container').fancytree({
    source: $.ajax({
        url: tree.cgi,
        dataType: "json"
    })
});
```

---

I'm using it in [Authentic Theme](https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme) for [Webmin](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/)/[Usermin](https://github.com/webmin/usermin/) for File Manager.

[image]

Try it on the best server management panel of the 21st Century  ♥️